# PHP: Dúvidas sobre a validação de input no front-end e no back-end

Tags: php, front-end, validação, back-end

As dúvidas são em relação de como fazer as validações no front-end e no back-end. Basicamente, as dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Caso a validação do front-end ser desabilitada como ficam as mensagens para o usuário?
- Como validar no javascript e no PHP sem ser redundante?
- Como ficam as validações de dados que não podem ser repetidos (como e-mail, por exemplo)? Elas devem ser validadas via Ajax ou somente no back-end?
- Quais bibliotecas (front-end e back-end) podem auxiliar nesse processo?

Comment: Ambam, a primeira por segurança e a segunda por usuabildade

Comment: ps: o downvote não é meu. Caro @rcs creio que sua pergunta não é bem um duplicata, mas ela precisa de detalhes, não existe uma maneira só de fazer, front-end é front-end,e back-end é back-end, a unica ligação que elas tem é pelo HTTP, vc pode tentar resolver de mil e umas formas a validação, mas seria amplo de mais e teria muitas formas, seria melhor vc editar e mostrar o que já fez, não existe solução pronta.

Answer (score 0):

Para segurança sempre Back End, as validações em Front End são facilmente ultrapassadas. Por exemplo se implementa as validações client side em Javascript facilmente o utilizador pode desativar o Javacript e aí tem a sua aplicação comprometida, diria que em Front End é mais uma questão de UX (Experiência de utilizador). Validar no Back End é garantia que independente do que o utilizador faz no Front End vai haver outra verificação! E mesmo assim eu quando uso base de dados ainda uso o máximo de funções para evitar que em caso de erro no Back End não sejam geradas inconsistências de dados, por exemplo não permitir campos com valor null, foreign keys, comprimento de campos, etc...
Quanto à comunicação do Backend com o Frontend dependendo da arquitectura que está a usar pode por exemplo retornar um array (em json caso use ajax, ou php caso gere o html no php) com mensagens/erros de validação, e em caso de sucesso retornar do mesmo modo a mensagem de sucesso ao Frontend.